# Did the Death Star have an external atmosphere?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

We know that the Death Star had an internal atmosphere due to the fact that living creatures reside in it without some form of breathing apparatus. We also know that there are at least two forms of vent-like activities performed on the Death Star: the reactor exhaust, and waste dumping. Considering the size of the Death Star, one could reason that a portion of any matter vented or released approximate to the Death Star would be caught by its gravitational pull and retained as atmosphere. Does the Death Star have an external atmosphere? Thanks

Comment: [You don't need to delete your question just because it's a duplicate.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7943/31394)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this. Lesson learned - thank you!